Integrate the product of a heaviside step and the absolute value?
I have a rather tricky integral here:
$$\underbrace{\int_0^R r_0\Theta(R-r_0)|r-r_0|dr_0}_{(1)} - \underbrace{\int_0^R r_0\Theta(R-r_0)|r+r_0|dr_0}_{(2)} \ \ \ \ \cases{0\le r < \infty \\ R=1}$$
and from the bounds of integration, we could also say $0\le r_0 \le R$. We could also express $|r-r_0| = \sqrt{r^2+r_0^2 - 2rr_0}$, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea for the integration process, so we'll use the piecewise definition: $|r-r_0| = \cases{r-r_0 & $r_0\le r$ \\ -(r-r_0) & $r_0>r$}$, and $|r+r_0| = \cases{r+r_0 & $r+r_0 \ge 0$ \\ -(r+r_0) & $r+r_0<0$}$

Here's my work so far:
From integration by parts:
$$(1)\cases{dv = \cases{rr_0-r_0^2 & $r_0\le r$ \\ -(rr_0-r_0^2) & $r_0>r$} & $u = \Theta(R-r_0)$ \\ v = \frac{1}{6}\cases{r_0^2(3r-2r_0) & $r_0\le r$ \\ -r_0^2(3r-2r_0) & $r_0>r$} & $du = -\delta(R-r_0)$}, $$
$$(2)\cases{dv = \cases{rr_0+r_0^2 & $r+r_0 \ge 0$ \\ -(rr_0+r_0^2) & $r+r_0<0$} & $u = \Theta(R-r_0)$ \\ v = \frac{1}{6}\cases{r_0^2(3r+2r_0) & $r+r_0\ge 0$ \\ -r_0^2(3r+2r_0) & $r+r_0<0$} & $du = -\delta(R-r_0)$}$$
$$= \underbrace{uv|_0^R - \int_0^Rvdu}_{(1)} - \Big(\underbrace{uv|_0^R - \int_0^Rvdu}_{(2)}\Big)$$
$$ = \underbrace{\frac{1}{6}\Theta(R-r_0)\cases{r_0^2(3r-2r_0) & $r_0\le r$ \\ -r_0^2(3r-2r_0) & $r_0>r$}|_0^R - \frac{1}{6}\int_0^R -\delta(R-r_0)\cases{r_0^2(3r-2r_0) & $r_0\le r$ \\ -r_0^2(3r-2r_0) & $r_0>r$}}_{(1)} -\underbrace{\frac{1}{6}\Theta(R-r_0)\cases{r_0^2(3r+2r_0) & $r+r_0\ge 0$ \\ -r_0^2(3r+2r_0) & $r+r_0<0$}|_0^R + \frac{1}{6}\int_0^R -\delta(R-r_0)\cases{r_0^2(3r+2r_0) & $r+r_0\ge 0$ \\ -r_0^2(3r+2r_0) & $r+r_0<0$}}_{(2)} $$
And we note that: $\int_0^a f(x)\delta(x-a)dx = f(a)\Big(2\Theta(a)-1\Big)$
$$= \underbrace{\frac{1}{6}\Theta(0)\cases{R^2(3r-2R) & $R\le r$ \\-R^2(3r-2R) & $R>r$}+\frac{1}{6}\Big(2\Theta(R)-1\Big)\cases{R^2(3r-2R) & $R\le r$ \\-R^2(3r-2R) & $R>r$}}_{(1)}\\ 
-\Big(\underbrace{\frac{1}{6}\Theta(0)\cases{R^2(3r+2R) & $r+R\ge 0$ \\ -R^2(3r+2R) & $r+R<0$}+\frac{1}{6}\Big(2\Theta(R)-1\Big)\cases{R^2(3r+2R) & $r+R\ge 0$ \\ -R^2(3r+2R) & $r+R<0$}}_{(2)}\Big) \\ 
=\underbrace{\frac{1}{6}R^2\Big(2\Theta(R)+\Theta(0)-1\Big)\cases{(3r-2R) & $R\le r$ \\-(3r-2R) & $R>r$}}_{(1)}-\bigg(\underbrace{\frac{1}{6}R^2\Big(2\Theta(R)+\Theta(0)-1\Big)\cases{(3r+2R) & $r+R\ge 0$ \\ -(3r+2R) & $r+R<0$}}_{(2)}\bigg)$$
$$\tag{3}=\frac{1}{6}R^2\Big(2\Theta(R)+\Theta(0)-1\Big)\bigg(\cases{(3r-2R) & $R\le r$ \\-(3r-2R) & $R>r$}-\cases{(3r+2R) & $r+R\ge 0$ \\ -(3r+2R) & $r+R<0$}\bigg) \\ = \frac{1}{6}R^2\Big(2\Theta(R)+\Theta(0)-1\Big)\Big(|3r-2R|-|3r+2R|\Big)$$
I'm not sure what I did wrong, but my expected result is supposed to be: $$\tag{4}\frac{4}{3}\bigg[\frac{R^3}{r}\Theta(r-R)+\frac{3R^2-r^2}{2}\Theta(R-r)\bigg]$$

As @lisyarus mentioned, it would be correct to simplify the integral due to the definition of $r_0$ due to the bounds of integration.
Additionally, I think I need to restructure my piecewise integrals:
For $\int_0^R r_0|r-r_0| dr_0= \int_0^R r_0\cases{r-r_0 & $r_0\le r$ \\ -(r-r_0) & $r_0>r$}dr_0$, I think it'd become: $\int_0^r rr_0-r_0^2 dr_0 + \int_r^R r_0^2-rr_0 dr_0$.
And for $\int_0^R r_0|r+r_0|dr_0 = \int_0^R r_0\cases{r+r_0 & $r+r_0 \ge 0$ \\ -(r+r_0) & $r+r_0<0$}dr_0$ would become: $\int_0^R rr_0+r_0^2 dr_0$ because $r+r_0<0$ should be impossible for the bounds of integration, so it becomes a regular integral instead of a piecewise one. Or it becomes $\int_0^{r+r_0} rr_0+r_0^2 dr_0$

I'm probably missing something, but since $0\leq r_0 \leq R$, wouldn't $\Theta(R-r_0)$ just be always equal to 1?

@lisyarus I think you're right, but from the desired result in (4), I think I'm supposed to keep it in its open form in the integrand

@lisyarus Hold on, I think you're right actually! I'll need to look over this problem some more.

The next thing I'd suggest to do is to merge the two integrals into one, and deal with the combined term $|r-r_0|-|r+r_0|$. When $r<r_0$, this is equal to $-2r$, otherwise it is $-2r_0$. Breaking the integration domain accordingly should simplify the integral using this formulas.

I like the direction that you're heading. When integrating Heaviside functions and/or absolute values, I recommend breaking up the integration domain into regions where they are constant and linear respectively. Then you have a few relatively simple integrals to consider rather than one nasty one.
That said, I don't think that integral is quite equivalent to the expected result you give in equation (4). I got something similar, but it's not exactly the same.
Our starting expression is given as:
$$\int_0^R r_0 \Theta(R-r_0)|r-r_0|dr_0-\int_0^R r_0 \Theta(R-r_0)|r+r_0|dr_0 \quad \begin{cases} 0\leq r \lt \infty \\ R=1 \end{cases}$$
Noting that the bounds and variables are the same, I'm going to bring them together and factor out some common terms.
$$=\int_0^R r_0 \Theta(R-r_0)(|r-r_0|-|r+r_0|)dr_0$$
As @lisyarus noted, $\Theta(R-r_0)=1$ over this integration range, so we can simplify a little bit.
$$=\int_0^R r_0 (|r-r_0|-|r+r_0|)dr_0$$
As noted in the edit, for the values of $r$ and $r_0$ of interest, $|r+r_0|=r+r_0$. So we can eliminate one of the absolute value functions. $$=\int_0^R r_0 (|r-r_0|-r-r_0)dr_0$$
Given the piecewise definition of absolute value, we can consider two different cases. The simpler case where $r>R$ (Therefore, $r>r_0$), and a case where $R>r$, where we can split that integration range into the region between $0$ and $r$ and the region between $r$ and $R$. This allows us to eliminate the remaining absolute value function. $$=\begin{cases} \int_0^R r_0 (r-r_0-r-r_0)dr_0 & \text{if} \quad r>R \\ \int_0^r r_0 (r-r_0-r-r_0)dr_0+\int_r^R r_0 (-r+r_0-r-r_0)dr_0 & \text{if} \quad  r<R \end{cases}$$
Simplifying all these integrands at once, $$=\begin{cases} \int_0^R -2r_0^2dr_0 & \text{if} \quad r>R \\ \int_0^r -2r_0^2dr_0+\int_r^R -2rr_0dr_0 & \text{if} \quad  r<R \end{cases}$$
And evaluating the integrals, we have$$=\begin{cases} -\frac{2}{3}r_0^3\vert_{r_0=0}^R & \text{if} \quad r>R \\ -\frac{2}{3}r_0^3\vert_{r_0=0}^r+(-rr_0^2)\vert_{r_0=r}^R& \text{if} \quad  r<R \end{cases}$$
And plugging in terms, we see $$=\begin{cases} -\frac{2}{3}R^3 & \text{if} \quad r>R \\ -\frac{2}{3}r^3-rR^2+r^3 & \text{if} \quad  r<R \end{cases}$$
If we prefer, we can use Heaviside functions to write this as $$=-\frac{2}{3}R^3\Theta(r-R)+(\frac{1}{3}r^3-rR^2)\Theta(R-r)$$
And from here, we can factor to get something similar to, but not exactly, (4). $$= -\frac{2r}{3}\left(\frac{R^3}{r}\Theta(r-R)+\frac{3R^2-r^2}{2}\Theta(R-r)\right)$$

Okay so the definition of $|r+r_0| = r + r_0$ is maintained over the bounds of integration from $0$ to $R$ not $0$ to $r+r_0$? That's was one other thing I wasn't sure about, but it looks like you've defined it as such on the bounds of $0$ to $R$.

Given the fact that $0\leq r < \infty$ and that $0\leq r_0 \leq R$ for any $R\geq 0$, we know $r+r_0\geq 0$. Thus, we can conclude that over the integration range, $|r+r_0|=r+r_0$

Makes sense! Thank you!
